# bringing functions into scope makes code to not compile

Tags: haskell

Consider the following snipet

```hs
-- This compiles
import Control.Monad

v :: Monad m => m b
v = undefined

w :: Monad m => m c
w = undefined

h :: Monad m => a -> m c
h = v' >=> w'
 where v' :: Monad m1 => a -> m1 b
       v' = const v
       w' :: Monad m2 => b -> m2 c
       w' = const w
```

It compiles fine and is able to solve `m ~ m1 ~ m2`, but if we bring `v` and `w` into `h` scope, then it wont compile any more: `` Couldn't match type `m1' with `m' ``

```hs
-- This doesn't compiles but looks equivalent to h

h' :: Monad m => m b -> m c -> a -> m c
h' v w = v' >=> w'
  where v' :: Monad m1 => a -> m1 b
        v' = const v
        w' :: Monad m2 => b -> m2 c
        w' = const w
```

I would think that both `h` and `h'` are equivalent when type resolution comes into play, since not in `h` nor `h'` assumptions over `m` are made. But it turns out that `h'` needs the help of `ScopedTypeVariables` to specify the `m ~ m1 ~ m2`

I seems weird that GHC does not complain in the `h` but is does in `h'`. Why `ScopedTypeVariables` is needed to compile `h'` but it isn't to compile `h`?

#### For the record

Just in case you wonder this is the version of `h'` which compiles. But notice the question is *why `ScopedTypeVariables` is not needed to compile `h`?* instead of *why `ScopedTypeVariables` is needed to compile `h'`?*

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
h' :: forall m a b c. Monad m => m b -> m c -> a -> m c
h' v w = v' >=> w'
  where v' :: Monad m => a -> m b
        v' = const v
        w' :: Monad m => b -> m c
        w' = const w
```

Comment: `v' :: Monad m => a -> m b` actually means `v' :: Monad m2 => a2 -> m2 b2` which is too general. You need `ScopedTypeVariables` and explicit `forall`s to tell GHC that `m2` is really the same as `m`.

Comment: @chi yes, and so it is in `h`. Notice that the question is _why you need `ScopedTypeVariables` in `h'` but you don't in `h`_. Let me edit the question so it is more clear

Comment: in your `h'` version of `v'` the `m` is **another**/different `m` (the compiler calls it `m1` here) - now the error is in using `v` on the right side as this implies `m ~ m1` but you claimed with `v' :: Monad m => ...` that it should work for **all** `m`s - that's where scoped-type variables come in - using it you can tell the compiler that you actually want the same `m` as in the definition of `v'` instead of a new one you just happened to shadow

Comment: I don't have time to write this as an answer - and not sure I know enough to write a "good" one anyway, but in essence: the types of `v` and `w` are not the same between the two snippets. In the first they apply to literally *any* Monad, independently chosen for each, whereas in the second they use the same Monad `m`.

Comment: @Carsten notice I do understand why `ScopedTypeVariables` is needed, what I am asking is about the apparent inconsistency between `h` compiling and `h'` not. I have added indeces to `m` to make my question clearer.

Comment: `ScopedTypeVariables` is not needed to compile `h'`. all you need to do is remove the type signatures for `v'` and `w'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TypeFamilies, RankNTypes, UnicodeSyntax #-}
```

Remember that signatures with type variables (which don't come from an enclosing scope) are implicitly universally quantified. I.e. your first example is

```
v :: ∀ m b . Monad m => m b
v = undefined

w :: ∀ m c . Monad m => m c
w = undefined

h :: ∀ m a c . Monad m => a -> m c
h = v' >=> w'
 where v' :: ∀ m₁ b . Monad m₁ => a -> m₁ b
       v' = const v
       w' :: ∀ m₂ b c . Monad m₂ => b -> m₂ c
       w' = const w
```

Let's do some α-renaming here to make it all match up, which you can always do with universally-quantified bindings: (the compiler does this under the hood in the above example)

```
v :: ∀ m₁ b . Monad m₁ => m₁ b
v = undefined

w :: ∀ m₂ c . Monad m₂ => m₂ c
w = undefined

h :: ∀ m a ζ . Monad m => a -> m ζ
h = v' >=> w'
 where v' :: ∀ m₁ b . Monad m₁ => a -> m₁ b
       v' = const v
       w' :: ∀ m₂ b c . Monad m₂ => b -> m₂ c
       w' = const w
```

However, in your second example, the types of `v` and `w` are *not* universally quantified. Instead, they have `m` rigid from the signature of `h'`. Thus you can't then use them in a local definition that *is* quantified universally. You would have to constrain it back to be equal to the outer `m`, but that would defeat the point of quantifying in the first place.

```
h' :: ∀ m a b c . Monad m => m b -> m c -> a -> m c
h' v w = v' >=> w'
  where v' :: ∀ m₁ . (Monad m₁, m₁~m) => a -> m₁ b
        v' = const v
        w' :: ∀ m₂ . (Monad m₂, m₂~m) => b -> m₂ c
        w' = const w
```

(Here, the `Monad m₁` / `Monad m₂` constraints are redundant, because we already know `Monad m` at that spot.)

What you want instead is `v` and `w` to be universally quantified, as they are in the first example. This makes the type of `h'` a *rank-2 type*:

```
h' :: ∀ m a b c . Monad m
       => (∀ m₁ . Monad m₁ => m₁ b) -> (∀ m₂ . Monad m₂ => m₂ c) -> a -> m c
h' v w = v' >=> w'
  where v' :: ∀ m₁ . Monad m₁ => a -> m₁ b
        v' = const v
        w' :: ∀ m₂ . Monad m₂ => b -> m₂ c
        w' = const w
```

Comment: can I use anything at all other that `return X` statements (or `do` blocks comprised only of `return X` statements) as arguments to your last rank-2 version? the original OP code (with the inner type signatures removed) allows for any `do` blocks as arguments as long as the two belong to the same monad, I believe. in particular it's supposed to be equivalent to `const (v >> w)` and so I could call `h (print 1) (print 2) ()` but this seems to be impossible with your version?

Comment: @WillNess well, I suppose the OP intends to actually use the `ScopeTypeVariables` version, but was just curious. — Indeed there's not much one can do in a `∀ m . Monad m => m A` value.

Comment: it would of course work with the `ScopedTypeVariables`  as well, since all it does is allows one to write explicitly that same type which is derived anyway when no explicit signatures are given...

Answer (score 3):

`ScopedTypeVariables` is not needed in the first case because the `where` definitions happen to be general enough.

I will clarify this point by inserting explicit type arguments `@T`, using `TypeApplications`.

Your first example actually means:

```
v :: forall m b. Monad m => m b
v = undefined

w :: forall m c. Monad m => m c
w = undefined
```

Note how `v` and `w` above expect two type arguments each. That is, we have to use them as in `v @M @B :: M B` (or let the compiuler infer the type arguments, of course).

Then `h` compiles because we can infer the correct type arguments. Again, I'll insert explicit `forall`s to make it clear:

```
h :: forall m a c. Monad m => a -> m c
h = (v' @m @a @T ) >=> (w' @m @T @c)
 where v' :: forall m1 a b. Monad m1 => a -> m1 b
       v' = const (v @m1 @b)
       w' :: forall m2 b c. Monad m2 => b -> m2 c
       w' = const (w @m2 @c)
```

where `@T` can be any arbitrary type. Indeed, GHC chooses `GHC.Types.Any` for that.

By comparison, your `h'` does *not* compile

```
h' :: Monad m => m b -> m c -> a -> m c
h' v w = v' >=> w'
  where v' :: Monad m1 => a1 -> m1 b1
        v' = const v
        w' :: Monad m2 => b2 -> m2 c2
        w' = const w
```

because here `v` is not a polymorphic value, we can't write `v @m1 @b` since `v` does not take any type arguments. We can only use `v :: m b` where `m` and `b` are type arguments for `h'`, but we would need something of type `m1 b1`, where `m1` and `b1` are type arguments for `v'`.